# App doesn't show on full screen in android 11

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUD0t.jpg)In android 10 app work correctly, in android 11 work like on screen. In android 12 it work correctly again, and in android 13 again like on screen. How can I fix it?

Maybe some api was deleted? I don't know how to fix this.
UPD:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dTBm.png) add image wth correctly work

Comment: I suggest that you post an image of the app working correctly and another image of the app **not** working correctly and describe what the actual problem is when the app does not work correctly.